# How can I track google analytics campaign using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics

I am using `vue`, `vue-analytics`

trying to track google analytics campaign with parameters from the url in the component:

```
export default {
  components: {
    Onboarding,
    Content,
  },
  name: 'Main',
  mounted() {
    this.$ga.page({
      page: '/?utm_source=linkedin&utm_medium=personal_message&utm_campaign=innerworks_linkedin_002',
      title: 'Main page',
    });
  },
};
```

But I can's see any updates in the campaign tab.
Do I use ga tracking in the correct way to track the campaign using UTM parameters?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about `vue-analytics` but I am using [vue-gtag](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag#readme).

If you want to use that here is how I am configuring it:

- Create a js file. (I create it in `src/plugins/google-analytics.js`)

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag'

if (['staging', 'production'].includes(process.env.VUE_APP_MODE)) {
  Vue.use(VueGtag, {
    config: {
      id: process.env.VUE_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_KEY,
      params: { anonymize_ip: true }
    }
  })
}
```

And then I import it in `main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import '@/plugins/google-analytics' // <= HERE
```

Make sure to take a look to [vue-gtag docs](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/).

[Take a look](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/auto-tracking) at Auto tracking to allow the plugin to track all your pages automatically.

Comment: thanks, 
vue-analytics works fine for the pageview tracking,
but for some reason, it does not track campaign